# Switch0 is configured as DHCP server but not working?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, dhcp, packet-tracer

Here I am not able to obtain ip automatically using DHCP. 
[image: My Topology of my DHCP Problem]

Here is configuration of swtich0 which is having DHCP Server.

```
Switch#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1237 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.4
!
ip dhcp pool accounts
network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 192.168.0.1
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
    !
interface FastEthernet0/1
switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
switchport mode trunk
!
interface F astEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!   
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
ip address 172.16.0.2 255.255.255.0
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
login   
line vty 5 15
login
!
!
!
end
```

Here the Configuration of Switch2

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1131 bytes
    !
    version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!   
interface FastEthernet0/12
!   
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!   
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface F astEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface F astEthernet0/24
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 172.16.0.3 255.255.255.0
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Please help me thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the PC in VLAN 10, but you don't have VLAN 10 defined in global configuration on your switches. Something like:

```
Vlan 10
 name PC_VLAN
!
```

Comment: solved with interface vlan 10 ip address 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0):

Excluding default gateway is not required on DHCP Configuration

`ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.4`

delete above command from DHCP Configuration .

Beacuse default -gateway status is already mentioned in DHCP Configuration

ip dhcp pool accounts

network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0

`default-router 192.168.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

On switch0 (the switch-dhcp server) add the interface vlan 10
with ip 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0
Then the PC can obtain IP and default-gateway.

Answer (score 0):

1. VLAN 10 doesn't exist on switch0 and needs to be created.
2. There's no DHCP address pool for VLAN 10 on switch0. Add.
3. Instead of allowing all VLANs on a VLAN trunk (by default), you should explicitly allow only the required VLANs on each trunk.